# Calling Web Method using Javascript on dynamically created Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webmethod

I am creating some controls dynamically in these Dynamic control there is `<asp: Image>` Control
I want to call webmethod  when I click that Image control.I searched a lot but nothing is happening.

the code for Dynamic control is

```
for (int i = 0; i < SearchResult.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl panel = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            panel.Attributes["class"] = "panel";
            panel.ID = "panel_" + (i + 1).ToString();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl inside = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            inside.Attributes["class"] = "inside";
            Image img = new Image();
            img.ImageUrl = SearchResult[i].ImageUrl;
           // img.Attributes.Add("onclick", THE WEB Method I want to call);
            inside.Controls.Add(img);
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = SearchResult[i].Title;
            label.Font.Size = 10;
            label.Font.Bold = true;
            panel.Controls.Add(label);
            panel.Controls.Add(inside);
            test.Controls.Add(panel);
        }
```

and my web method is

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void AddToDownload(String ConnectionString,String Query)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried a jQuery approach of wiring up the click event for the dynamically created images? You can apply data dash (i.e. data-id=) attributes to your ASP.NET Image controls and then the jQuery click event handler (read: anonymous or named function) can read out those data dash values and use an AJAX call to invoke the web method on the server.

Comment: No, I have no idea about that approach

Comment: So are you trying to get the JavaScript onClick event to fire so that the page does not perform a postback and flicker the screen?

Comment: WEll my main purpose is to insert data in database and to redirect to a new page . I dont care about these post backs. I just want the main task done.

Comment: To be precise if u visit this link [link](http://www.karokuch.com/Result.aspx?SearchID=229c7fc5-a1ec-4ad7-ac73-b57b0f6f0646&IP=92.40.254.53)  You will see a image slider. the images on that slider are created by the code I have provided above. I want to click it, add some data into db and redirect to other page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the "onclick" line and wire up a server-side Click event, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var img1 = new ImageButton
        {
            ID = "ImageButton1", 
            AlternateText = "Button 1"
        };
    img1.Click += img_Click;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(img1);

    var img2 = new ImageButton
        {
            ID = "ImageButton2", 
            AlternateText = "Button 2"
        };
    img2.Click += img_Click;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(img2);
}

private void img_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    var whoClicked = (sender as ImageButton).ID;
}
```

I have changed your Image server controls to ImageButton server controls to more easily accommodate the Click event.

Each of the two buttons is wired up to a common event handler and then in the event handler it is casting the sender (the control that initiated the event) to an ImageButton and then grabbing its ID to distinguish between the two buttons. You would want to put a null check there in case something besides an ImageButton initiates a click event.

Let me know if you need anything clarified or have further questions.

Comment: I tried Image buttons, but the messed up the display so I had to stick with the Image controls only but I have solved a problem by other way. Thanks

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.  Good luck with the rest of your work.