# How to avoid postback while clicking the asp imagebutton?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How to avoid postback while clicking the asp imagebutton from click event.

When i clicking the button its take postback but i don't want the postback from everyclick event. So, how to write the javascript function while avoiding button click.

ASP:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnproductadd" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Add a Product" OnClientClick="return myFunc();"
ImageUrl="../../images/add-icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" Width="15px" Height="15px" />
```

Vb.Net

```
Private Sub btnproductadd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnproductadd.Click
    If cboproductgroup.SelectedValue = "" Then
        radnote.Text = "Select the product group."
        radnote.Show()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboproductname.SelectedValue = "" Then
        radnote.Text = "Select the product."
        radnote.Show()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    objdbconn.OpenConn()

    msSQL = " select product_gid from crm_tmp_tproductrequest where product_gid='" & cboproductname.SelectedValue & "'"
    objtbl = objdbconn.GetDatatable(msSQL)
    If objtbl.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "showalert", "alert('This product already added.');", True)
        popwindow(radcalllog)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    msGetcalproductgid = objcmnfunctions.getMasterGID("BCLP")
    If msGetcalproductgid = "E" Then
        objdbconn.CloseConn()
        radnote.Text = "Create sequence code BCLP for product details"
        radnote.Show()
        Exit Sub
    End If


    msSQL = " Insert into crm_tmp_tproductrequest " & _
                    " (tmpproductrequest_gid," & _
                    " product_gid," & _
                    " productuom_gid," & _
                    " productgroup_gid," & _
                    " created_by ) " & _
                    " values (" & _
                    "'" & msGetcalproductgid & "'," & _
                    "'" & hdnproduct_gid.Value & "'," & _
                    "'" & hdnproductuom_gid.Value & "'," & _
                    "'" & cboproductgroup.SelectedValue & "'," & _
                    "'" & Session("user_gid") & "')"
    mnResult = objdbconn.ExecuteNonQuerySQL(msSQL)
    If mnResult = 1 Then
        radnote.Text = "Product added successfully."
        radnote.Show()
        cboproductname.Text = ""
        cboproductgroup.ClearSelection()
    End If
    objdbconn.CloseConn()
    popwindow(radcalllog)
End Sub
```

I have tried to JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc() {
            alert("My New Function");
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

But, this function is not working.

Comment: Which one is your actual requirement? avoid `postback` or have to trigger the `javascript alert`?

Comment: button click event work without postback.., this is my requirement

Comment: Since you are using `<asp:ImageButton/>` it definitely causes `postback`. you can use `<img>` instead for this and call the back-end method through ajax call/Web method. hence your img tag will be looks like the following: `<img src="../../images/add-icon.gif" onClick='myFunc();'/>`

Comment: how to write button click event from <img>

Comment: this thread may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153035/calling-web-method-using-javascript-on-dynamically-created-control

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `<asp:imagebutton>` with a normal `<img>` element and bind and handle a click event on the image. This is done fairly simply with jQuery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#imageToClick").on("click", function() {
            alert("Clicked!");
        });
    });
</script>
<img id="imageToClick" />
```

Obviously you can replace the alert with whatever you want to do with the click.
Regarding the code-behind function, you can't fire that without a postback. Like said in comments, use an ajax call and web api for that.